# YII Active Record Join

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, many-to-many

I am looking at YII for the first day, and i'm having some problems trying to work out the relations between some tables.

my table structure is as follows:

Pets:
pet_id
pet_name
....

Pet_Owner_Link
pet_id
owner_id

Owner:
owner_id
owner_name

How would I go about getting all of the pets that belong to an owner? Really struggling to get my head around the AR relations at the moment.

Comment: Why do you need the `Pet_Owner_Link` table instead of simply a `Pet.owner_id` column? Do you foresee a pet having multiple owners? Have you read the documentation with examples - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this comment by DD.Jarod on the Yii AR documentation page: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#c970

"If you declare a many to many relationship, the order of keys inside the jointable declaration must be 'my_id, other_id':

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
        'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
            'tbl_post_category(post_id, category_id)'),
    );
  }
}
class Category extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
        'Posts'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Post',
            'tbl_post_category(category_id, post_id)'),
    );
  }
}
```

So your code would look like:

```
class Owner extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
        'pets'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Pet',
            'tbl_post_category(pet_id, owner_id)'),
    );
  }
}
class Pet extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
        'owners'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Post',
            'tbl_post_category(owner_id, pet_id)'),
    );
  }
}
```

Your problem may be that your primary keys for Pet and Owner by default should be id (not pet_id / owner_id).  Yii may be getting confused if you don't clarify that your primary keys don't match the default naming convention / aren't setup as primary keys in the database.  You can specify what your primary key is in a model like this:

```
public function primaryKey()
{
    return 'owner_id';
}
```

Finally, you would retrive the information like this:

```
$owner = Owner::model()->findByPk((int)$id);
foreach($owner->pets as $pet)
{
    print $pet->name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not exactly what you ask, but this is how I do it.

Add this item in your relations() return in Owner model :

```
'all_pets'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Pet_Owner_Link','owner_id'),
```

Add this item in your relations() return in Pet_Owner_Link model :

```
'pet'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Pet', 'pet_id'),
```

Then get a pet like this

```
$owner->all_pets[$i]->pet;
```

Comment: That works in certain situations (I've run into it when I needed to sort and do other things on the link table), but it's usual far cleaner / clearer if you use the AR MANY_MANY relationship instead.

Comment: Why rating -1 for this answer? I understand it's not the chosen one, but -1 is for non sense answers, which is not the case.